Eclipse MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error

Hi everyone!
I had a problem with my Eclipse Marketplace when I searched how to show Copilot Chat (because I don't have the option).
I want to look if my Copilot is up to date, but my Marketplace show me an error:
MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Unexpected response for '4123770,3184658,4528322,1789419,1617241,1166,5578890,
1963651,2177882,2953952,2963451,1336,5321178,5026683,3274405,2963400'

Thanks for your help!


I try to access to Eclipse Marketplace

Click the "Show Error Log" link and show us what that says

Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

When I click on the link "Show Error Log" nothing is happing...

Can you find the  Error Log view in Window > Show View?
